# webdriver maven archetype

Tags: java, maven, maven-archetype

How to find maven project archetype for a webdriver project?

I tried google it, but with no luck. where can I find this archtype? I bet it exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/sebarmeli/Selenium2-Java-QuickStart-Archetype) seems the best option from what I find; I've never seen a publicly-published archetype.